# Django Sql ERROR 1064 when accessing table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, database

I cannot access one of the tables in my database. I can't even delete the table by myself, so I am not sure what to do. Here is the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match' at line 1
```

So this error appears every time I am doing an operation on that table (describe, select, drop, etc.)

I have deleted the model from my code, but that doesn't remove the table from the db.

Comment: You need to include the generated query that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of speculation.  But the error is referring to `match`.  It might not be obvious, but `match` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL.  It is used for full-text searches.

If you have a column or table named `match` and it is being referred to without escape characters (backticks), then you would likely get an error like this.

The thing to do is to fix the name of the table/column so it does no conflict with a reserved word.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you!